# Book on brief overview(or outline) of Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

That doesn't go into much detail but gives a brief overview(or outline) of entire mathematics.

Basically I'm looking for a book that talks about these topics - [In this Link](http://gogeometry.com/education/mathematics_fields_mind_map.html), but in a bit more detail.

Comment: I don't think there exists a single book that covers all the topics mentioned in the link but rather I can suggest you books which talks about few of those topics collectively.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [Mathematics: A Very Short Introduction](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780192853615.do) by Timothy Gowers.

At the other end of the spectrum, [The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html).